# Design Populate in jquery-tokeninput

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tokeninput

In my project I am using `jQuery-tokenInput` every thing works fine, but now I want to do some custom **design** to **Populate** that come up with results. Like I want to increase the width of it, or any other design. 

I don't know how can I achieve it.
[image]

Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/jigarb1992/5feykLes/3/

Comment: Do you have some test code that you can share? This way it will much easier to help you.

Comment: sorry for too late @GeorgeAntonakos . I have added the jsfiddler link please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really quick way to start theming the plugin would be to check what configuration the plugin provides from their Github page.

Furthermore you can override the provided plugin css to satisfy your needs.
In this case to change the width of the dropdown panel you can override the width for this selector `.token-input-dropdown` and that will work.